# Script for connecting to remote server (via another desktop) from my laptop using cygwin

Tags: windows-8, ssh, cygwin

I need to connect to my university server (S) from home using my laptop (L). Since I am off campus (and my VPN does not work for some reason), I am required to first login (SSH) to my desktop (D) at the university, and then connect to S (since the server only accepts connections from computers on the campus network).

I am using Cygwin on Windows 8. I would like to know how I can create a script to auotmate this process - currently I have to manually SSH from L to D, and then again from D to S. I am new to unix.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

--- Edit ---

Specifically, I would like to know how I can automate this process so that I don't have to enter my password every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` accepts a command to execute at the remote host after connecting. You can use that to launch a second ssh session:

```
ssh -t D ssh S
```

You'll be prompted for your desktop password first, then for your server password.

By the way, I recommend looking into GNU screen if you're not already using it. It prevents losing any work in case your SSH connection drops out.

To automate this even more, stick it in a bash file called "connect-university.sh":

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -t D ssh S
```

You can then run that file from the Cygwin commandline via:

```
./connect-univiersity.sh
```

Note that the `./` part is essential, as Cygwin doesn't usually look for executable files in the current directory for security reasons.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an option via a bash script.

Comment: That helped, thanks. But sorry, I did not pose my question right. I was wanting to know how I could do this without having to enter my password every time.

Comment: Look into creating [SSH keys](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys). However, this is quickly becoming off-topic for Stackoverflow; it's probably better to direct further questions toward [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).

Comment: Got it. I am now able to get a lot of it working (I can go from D to S without password, but not from L to D for some reason. I think it is because my username on L is different from that in D and S). But will have to post on superuser anyway I think. One final question. Is there a way to run the command as "connect-university" instead of as "./connect-university.sh"?

Comment: Name the file however you like. The ``#!/bin/bash`` line states how the file will be executed. Set the username for connecting to S using the ``-l`` argument: ``ssh -t D ssh -l username S``.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That solved all of my problems (and saved me hours of fiddling around). Just love SO !